# Why doesn't NASA create targeted campaigns for donations?

Tags: nasa, future-missions, cost

In [this article](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn25677-us-must-play-nice-with-china-to-put-astronauts-on-mars.html) is stated that in order to land on Mars NASA might need the help of the ESA or even the Chinese, not because it doesn't have the capability, but because it needs more financial help. Of course for the moment this collaboration might get little traction in the US government because of security reasons. Although little publicized, it appears that NASA [accepts donations](http://spaceindustrynews.com/how-to-donate-to-nasa/), but you can't suggest/know what [they](http://nodis3.gsfc.nasa.gov/displayDir.cfm?Internal_ID=N_PD_1210_001G_&page_name=main) do with your money. Probably this type of approach doesn't create a sense of accomplishment within the people that manage to find out they can actually donate to NASA. My question is what legal biases prevents NASA from launching targeted, well advertised campaigns (kickstarter [like](http://www.rockethub.com/projects/42228-isee-3-reboot-project-by-space-college-skycorp-and-spaceref)), that could raise a part of the money needed for specific missions?

Comment: Reminds me of these folks: http://www.penny4nasa.org/ Of course, they're talking public sector rather than private donation.

Comment: A mission to Mars is too expensive for kickstarter.

Comment: @JerardPuckett nice example, it's not targeted, but a step in the right directions I guess

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I wasn't referring just that particular mission, but any specific mission like "help us not [cancel the Cassini](http://www.wired.com/2013/11/end-of-cassini-science/) mission". I also mentioned "raise a part of the money", I don't expect a successful Kickstarter campaign of over 1 billion like the Curiosity mission :)

Comment: [SOFIA](http://www.sofia.usra.edu/) might be worth saving like this. Good question!

Comment: Can a kickstarter be used to collect money for lobbying during NASA budget discussions in congress?

Comment: A mission to Mars might be too expensive, but maybe a stepping stone could be provided. Hmmm...

Comment: @TildalWave Maybe if [ISEE-3](http://www.space.com/26075-nasa-isee3-spacecraft-contact-success.html) proves a success, NASA might consider outsourcing other projects they can't afford anymore like SOFIA.

Comment: @symbiotech SOFIA's future seems to be safe for now, Senate Appropriations Committee just approved FY2015 Commerce-Justice-Science (CJS) appropriations bill that includes \$87 M to continue operations and not scrape it in 2015 for \$12 M. I also consider crowdfunded [ISEE-3 Reboot Project](http://rkthb.co/42228) a success. They've proven that software defined radio communications with an old probe are possible with a bit of funding, perseverance and competence. The probe seems to be in good health. NASA missed a big opportunity to organize a summer camp and train their people in something new.

Comment: Because government then would lower NASA's budget with the same amount next year. They don't need as much tax money if they can finance themselves in other ways.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Per  https://standards.nasa.gov/documents/viewdoc/3315318/3315318 .

NASA Policy Directive
COMPLIANCE IS MANDATORY
NPD 1210.1G
Effective Date: April 28, 2010
Subject: Acceptance and Use of Monetary Gifts and Donations
Responsible Office: Office of the Chief Financial Officer

1. POLICY The National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA) may accept and utilize monetary gifts, donations, or bequests given as cash, check, or money order, ***provided they are unsolicited and offered without conditions on their use***.
   (Emphasis added)

Comment: I used a different [link](http://nodis3.gsfc.nasa.gov/displayDir.cfm?Internal_ID=N_PD_1210_001G_&page_name=main) for the same document and already stated in my question that I know they can accept donations. My question was why don't they do this in an "organised", targeted and well advertised way.

Comment: @symbiotech: Did you read the quote above?  NASA is _expressly forbidden_ from soliciting donations.  This definitively and authoritatively answers your question.

Comment: @Mark Adler: And, even if someone else does the campaigning, since they cannot specify what NASA is to do with the funds thus raised, any donation would be made to the general NASA budget, not to any one specific program.

Comment: That's correct.  Though while NASA has no obligation as to how it spends the money, it does not prevent NASA from honoring the request of the donor.  I suspect that in such a case, NASA would tend to honor the request.

Comment: @MarkAdler You are correct, I focused too much on the "without conditions" and the "unsolicited" part escaped my attention in spite of reading that paragraph more than three times. Any idea why they're not allowed "to beg" money?

Comment: I don't know, but I can guess that it's related to the fact that government agencies can't lobby or market on their own behalf in order to get the public to tell their congressmen to send NASA more money.  NASA has to walk a fine line between their charter of outreach and education, and congressional prohibitions on self-marketing.

Answer (score 8):

To expand on the currently accepted answer: The "unconditional gifts only" rule is not NASA-driven policy, it's a matter of federal law. Specifically, three laws control this. The Miscellaneous Receipts Act requires that any money that a federal agency receives, absent any other statutory authority, has to go into the general treasury -- unless a federal law specifically allows an agency to collect money, whatever you give them is treated as a gift to the United States. The Antideficiency Act says that an agency can't spend money that was not appropriated for it under most circumstances (important exception: agency trust funds). So, for a generic federal agency, if you donate money they have to forward it to the general treasury. If you donate money to the US under the condition it go to that agency, that condition is binding, but just means the government can't accept the gift without Congressional authorization (as Congress must approve all gifts that impose some duty on the US).

Now, NASA is not a generic federal agency: they have specific statutory authority to accept gifts. But that authority only goes so far as unconditional gifts -- they can be accepted and are auto-appropriated for NASA by going into the NASA trust fund, but nothing else can be accepted. They can also enter into contracts, but they can't make profit off those contracts - it's limited to reimbursement. So, because NASA lacks statutory authority to accept conditional gifts, they cannot do so without the consent of Congress -- otherwise it'd involve putting money in their trust fund that they have no authority to keep, as well as spending money they have not been appropriated.

Incidentally, for *why* federal agencies need special authority to accept gifts, there are various solid public policy reasons involving checks and balances. But that's not on-topic here: the point is it's illegal for NASA to accept conditional gifts, not because of their own policy, but by act of Congress.

Answer (score 5):

As noted, NASA cannot campaign for donations.  However, even if someone else does the campaigning for them (e.g. the Planetary Society), the amount of funds you might expect to get are small in comparison to what is needed for a mission.  The Planetary Society managed to raise \$4M at one point to build a solar sail spacecraft, which is quite impressive, but down about three orders of magnitude from NASA annual spending on space science.  Similarly, the [largest kickstarter campaign so far](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/ryangrepper/coolest-cooler-21st-century-cooler-thats-actually) raised \$13M (for an advanced beverage cooler).

Another common question along these lines is selling advertising on spacecraft.  The Coca Cola or Nike logo on Mars might be worth something to them.  It turns out that the amounts are quite similar, where such an opportunity would be worth a few \$M to at the very most a small integer times \$10M.  Note that a Super Bowl 60-second spot costs \$8M, and that will likely have many more viewers than a Mars mission.

By the way, since you're keen on this, the Planetary Society's Light Sail 1 is scheduled to launch in 2016, and they are [accepting donations here](https://secure.planetary.org/site/Donation2?3440.donation=form1&df_id=3440).  NASA just [cancelled their project to launch a solar sail](http://www.spacenews.com/article/civil-space/42227nasa-nixes-sunjammer-mission-cites-integration-schedule-risk).

Comment: I think something like a manned mars mission would be watched by more people than the super bowl, so advertisers would be willing to pay a lot for that.

Comment: @CBredlow "to at the very most a small integer times $10M" - Mark already accounted for the possibility of something like that.